# How do I designate an index as log data?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In my Elasticsearch instance, I have an index that contains log data being pushed from a different system. I'm trying to set up a Kibana dashboard to view the logs. There is a Kibana component specifically for this. But I can't point it at my index. What do I need to do to tell Elasticsearch and Kibana that this index is full of logs and can be displayed as such?

I don't have much control over how the logs are sent to Elasticsearch. It looks like the Logs Elasticsearch is looking for require some form of integration that I cannot use.

I've tried setting a `type` of `logs` on the documents. I've also tried creating a data stream and forwarding the documents there. Neither are giving me the option to see the documents in the Kibana logs dashboard component.